# setUp function being called multiple times in django TestCase

Tags: django, django-testing

I am using django unit tests for the first time. Following is a sized down version of my code.

My assumption was that setUp function would be called once for each TestCase class. But when I run the python manage.py test command, setUp function is called once for each of the test function.

Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong in my assumption?

```
class SampleTest(TestCase):
    """
        This class assumes an archiver setup with
            add available at localhost:9101
            query available at localhost:9105
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.init_var = False
        super(SampleTest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(self):
        """"""
        print "setup called"
        self.init_var = True


    def test_1(self):
        print "Test 1", self.init_var

    def test_2(self):
        print "Test 2", self.init_var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is wrong. Each test inside a test case should be independent; so `setUp` (and `tearDown`) is called once for each of them.

If you really need something to be only done once for the whole class, use `setUpClass`; but note that you shouldn't be doing things like setting up data there.

Comment: How should I address use cases where I have to test multiple multiple logic points of a code which does some additions/deletion to the database. I am not only setting up data in the setup function. The logic I have to test does changes to the database and I have to test if the various intended objects are created in the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. How does that prevent you doing it for each test?

Answer (score 4):

This is because `setUp` is called each time a test case is called. If you want to call it only one time, you have to use `setUpClass` with the `@classmethod` decorator, like following:

```
class SampleTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SampleTest, cls).setUpClass()
        # your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a little frustrated with this myself. There is often set up that needs to be done that all tests will rely on. If you're modifying the data that you created during that setup, though, you could really mess yourself up. If you're absolutely certain this is what you want to do, you can use the following as a base class instead of the standard Test Case. Then, instead of using `setUp` to set up the test, use either `before_running_all_tests` or `before_running_each_test` depending on what you need to do.

```
class TestCasePlus(TestCase):
    _one_time_setup_complete = False

    def before_running_all_tests(self):
        pass

    def before_running_each_test(self):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        if not self._one_time_setup_complete:
            self.before_running_all_tests()
        self.before_running_each_test()
```